# How to fix - Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, npm-install, npm-start

I am working on a project of react and I am getting the following error after implement this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-bootstrap-typeahead then i get the following error.

```
Failed to compile

./node_modules/react-popper/lib/cjs/Popper.js
Module not found: Can't resolve '@babel/runtime/helpers/objectWithoutPropertiesLoose' in 'E:\reactjs\deveans-react-version\node_modules\react-popper\lib\cjs'

This error occurred during the build time and cannot be dismissed.
```

I found many solutions and I tried it too https://github.com/jquense/yup/issues/216 but still getting same error.

But when i remove Typeahead component then it works fine.

```
import React , { Component } from 'react'
import {Typeahead} from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css';
class States extends Component {

    state = {
        multiple: false,
        options: [
          {id: 1, label: 'Pakistan'},
          {id: 2, label: 'Indonesia'},
          {id: 3, label: 'Turkey'},
          {id: 4, label: 'Brazil'},
        ]
      };

    render () {

        const {multiple} = this.state;

        return (
          <div>
            <Typeahead
            labelKey="label"
            multiple={multiple}
            options={this.state.options}
            placeholder="Choose a state..."
          />
          </div>
        )
    }
}
export default States
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found a solution

```bash
npm install --save-exact @babel/runtime@7.0.0-beta.55
```

Then delete the `package-json.lock` file and `node_modules` folder then re-install with `npm install`.

It works for me.

Comment: Just saving the recent version of `@babel/runtime` as answered by @Kenn was enough for me, no need for a specific beta version.

Answer (score 49):

You can install `@babel/runtime` to fix the problem:

Using npm:

`npm install --save @babel/runtime`

Using yarn:

`yarn add @babel/runtime`

Answer (score 18):

Make sure you got `@babel/runtime` installed into your regular `dependencies` and not the `devDependencies` (leave out the `--dev` or the `-D` flag when installing).

```
npm i @babel/runtime
```

OR

```
yarn add @babel/runtime
```

Else it's going to be missing when doing a production installation (which leaves out the `devDependencies` section), which is what happened to me.

All provided answers are correct in most cases but I wanted to add an explanation:
Babel's runtime is [a production runtime that ships with your code](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10584#issuecomment-544725354) so it can't just be left out because it runs on the client.

Answer (score 5):

For me, i solve this by adding `js` and `jsx` as a resolvable extensions as `objectWithoutPropertiesLoose` is without extension at `webpack.config.js` exports:

```
resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".jsx"]
},
```

Comment: Yeah this worked for me as well. the problem I ran into is I had mjs modules that when exported did not include the extension inside the `index.mjs` and therefore webpack couldn't resolve the file extensions and I would get a similar runtime error as mentioned in the original question. Adding `.mjs` to the array fixed it in my scenario. I would say if your webpack is complaining that it can't resolve the module try this first since it is simple and you would just add it to your webpack config.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I have to use these configurations on my webpack.config.js file

```
module: {
 rules: [
   {
     test: /\.m?js/,
     resolve: { fullySpecified: false },
   },
 ],
}
```

I know this is an old issue, but it may help someone else

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with pnpm and solved it by adding in `.npmrc` :

```
hoist-pattern[]=@babel/runtime
```

and install `@babel/runtime` to production dependencies (no -D flag!)

```
pnpm add @babel/runtime
```